# Map parameters to the query in oracle reports

Tags: oraclereports

I have created two bind date parameters in oracle reports on top of that I have created 3 more general parameters but I am unable to map those parameters to the query.

Please help me how to map the parameters(other than bind parameters).

Answer (score 0):

as i have understood your question is that you want to know how to include the parameters you have made into the query. for this just write as below ..suppose your parameter name is p_from_date. now u want to query the value where there the value is equal to your parameter. then it could be written as 
where effective_date=:p_from_date.